# What is the best way to proxy / rewrite URL with gcp to hide secrets without spawning a function / service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway, gcp-load-balancer

I have an app which calls an external provider which needs a key in the URL. For security reasons I can't include the key in the app to call the external API directly. Therefore I need to proxy this URL / rewrite URL and attach the key in the URL like following:

https://api.xxx.com/maps/3/2/2.png

to

https://api.xxx.com/maps/3/2/2.png?key=xxxxxxxx

What's the best way to solve it with gcp?